# View multiple images with Lightbox

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have a list of projects in a view with one image for each project, which is displayed with Lightbox.
The client asked me if it is possible to:

- Have more than 1 image, but show the first one (done)
- Clicking on the image, make the other images visible

How can I achieve this? Is there any method that is not changing the image formatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Colorbox instead:

Formatter: Colorbox
Content image style: Hide (do not display image)
Content image style for first image: Thumbnail
Colorbox image style: None (original image)
Gallery (image grouping): Per post gallery

Under 'multiple field settings' I set it to display 'all', choosing Display type: 'Simple separator' and changing this from ', ' to ' '.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1026112 #50

Comment: I don't understand, why this answer was down voted from other users :-/ 1+!

Answer (score 0):

Possible in views. You can use Rewrite Code in first image settings under view edit page. Here you can type your own custom html using fields inserted in the said view.
For example:
first-image

Comment: why? the answer from @P.Roy is right!

Comment: User is using LightBox and not ColorBox. It can be achieved with LightBox as well.